# One Admin, two websites, one with tax in Euro and one without tax in Dollar?

Tags: magento-1.7, price, tax, currency, websites

we have one store in which we have tax and sell in Euros. I would like to setup a second website, not store view, and then have prices in Dollar and without tax.
The Dollar price should not be recalculated automatically. I have different dollar prices that shouldn't get converted from Euro.

For example Product ABC is
Website Store Europe = 199,- Euro incl. Tax
Website Store USA = 179,- Dollar excl. Tax

The price should be shown on the Product Details Page.
Is this possible out of the box?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct, use website pricing, but that is where the fun really begins. You need to keep the prices up to date manually for the non-default base currency. That impacts fx conversions, local checkout currencies was a 'hack' in Magento to move it to the business side rather than rewrite the code. You need to provide USD and Euro checkout, but what about GBP, they won't want to buy in EUR. It is possible out of the box, Magento basically supports ~20% international sales (due to its pricing problems), up to 50% with specialist tools, above that you need a handful of very specialist consultants.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test but I think this is possible out of the box.
after creating your second website you need to set the price attribute scope to `website`.
Do this from `System->Configuration->Catalog->Price->Catalog Price Scope`

Then set a different base currency for your second website.
Go to `System->Configuration->Currency Setup->Currency Options`. Select from the top left dropdown your second website and change the values for `Base Currency`, `Default Display Currency` and `Allowed Currencies`.

Then you need to change the taxes.
Go to `System->Configuration->Tax`. Select again your second website and take a look inside all the fieldsets to see what you need to change.