# Third language should have own configuration

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

Today my store support two different languages. Where the root domain is English and /no is Norwegian. They both share the same prices with NOK being the base currency.

However we are about to add a third language. For SEO purposes we need the domain to remain intact and just add a sub folder like the Norwegian purpose. However the third language need to have its own base price, cost, tax settings and more.

Is this possible and if so, how do I create the third language to be "independent".

Comment: Sure you can if you create new website, prices and qty are assigned per webstore - you shouldn't create new store view

Comment: or if you want to use store view you can use a module http://innoexts.com/promotion/store-view-pricing/#.Vo--CBWLRaR

Comment: Would that include taxes as well. So just this view can have taxes for instance?

Comment: yes with website you can have separate price, tax and qty. after you create the website you need to assign your products to the new website

Comment: But how do I set tax-setting on website level?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158123/magento-tax-rates-multiple-countries and this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/one-admin-two-websites-one-with-tax-in-euro-and-one-without-tax-in-dollar

Comment: you need to create different rules fore each website

Comment: For your future references please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994888/multi-store-and-multi-stock-with-magento

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a new website with base_url as {main_domain}/subfolder.
With this you can configure a different currency, all the other thing and keep the main domain intact.

---

Here you can find a quick tutorial to setup a new website : http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/
Please take care, the part configuring the `secure` and `unsecure` URLs here you have to fill `{main_domain}/subfolder`

Comment: So we should be able to set this up using `domain.com/new_lang` but with this new language have its own `tax` `prices` etc?

Comment: Yes with a new webiste you can do all this configuration. Keep in mind that website is like a new shop in Magento so you can configure it the way you want.

Comment: Is this the same as a storeview? Usure of the actual setup

Comment: When you create a new website it is a copy of the "Default" configuration. Of course it is a "feature" in Magento if you want to manage stock separatly you have to use a module for that (for example https://www.wyomind.com/fr/advanced-inventory-magento.html). You can give a try to create a new website you will see that you can configure anything you want as you asked. It is the point of Magento multi-website feature ;)

Comment: Ok, so it's a `Website`. Not a `Store` or `Store view` and with that we should be able to have third language as `folder` without messing up the existing two.

Comment: Yes it is a website `System > Manage Stores > Create Website`. Please check my answer update I give you a tutorial to create a new website you can use it to create yours. Like I say in my update for URL setting you have to fill `{main_domain}/subfolder`

Answer (score 2):

You can't with Store view only website

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994888/multi-store-and-multi-stock-with-magento

> Prices cannot be specified per store, only per website and then only
>   if you turn on the option in System > Configuration > Catalog > Price.
>
> Stock can only be controlled globally - which makes sense because you
>   either have stock or you don't. Instead change the Status to disabled
>   for whichever site you wish.

If you want to keep using store views you can use module:
https://github.com/careysizer/Magento-StoreLevel-Stock
http://innoexts.com/promotion/store-view-pricing/#.Vo_BnRWLRaQ

With website you can manage prices and qty separately